# Is there a way to make Android tabs slide?

Tags: android, tabs, move, slide, touches

I'm new to Android development, and I was wondering if anyone knew either how to make Tabs slide, or how to get a similar effect without tabs. I have quite a few tabs in my application, and it does not look good on devices with smaller screens. Or maybe tabs are not what I am looking for. If you don't know what I'm talking about, I'd like to reproduce something similar to Photoshop.com Mobile's effects screen.

I know this is possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't experimented w/ sliding tabs, but I know other applications I have used have a panel at the top with buttons, and that is slide-able so that you can slide for the content needed and select.  It does the same thing without the tabs, and should only be a little more overhead from the code side of things.

Comment: Okay, well then I suppose the question is how to make the buttons move and respond to swipes. 

Sorry if this is a really newbie question. I'm coming over from the iPhone world, and on the iPhone, there is a class called UIScrollView I could use. Is there something similar for Android?

Comment: I would start with a horizontalScrollView.  http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

this should handle the swipe input for you.