# how to place one activity on another activity

Tags: android

friend's,
   i have an task to set horizontal swipe tabs below the header,how can i set an activity on another activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a layout which is the zone where you want to put your activity. Take a look at [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LocalActivityManager.html#startActivity(java.lang.String,%20android.content.Intent))

```
TheLayout.removeAllViews();
View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id, intent).getDecorView();
TheLayout.addView(view, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [Is there a way to make Android tabs slide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617388/is-there-a-way-to-make-android-tabs-slide)

Answer (score 0):

checkout TabActivity and TabHost in android developer site
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html
this might help you